# Is there a to-do multi-list app for Android with cross-list items that can share checked state?

Tags: android, todo

I'm trying to find a "to-do" list type app for Android to replace a couple other apps I had on my old phone; I was never able to find one that did what I wanted, so I'm trying to crowdsource it a bit and see if anyone knows about a list app with these features (in no particular order):

- Supports to-do checked/unchecked item lists.
- Can sort lists alphabetically, based on check state, and both.
- Supports multiple lists.
- Allows list items to span lists (e.g. superset-subset; cherry-picked items).
- Option for spanned list items to inherit their checked/unchecked status.
- Will work without net access.
- Small footprint, minimal permissions.

Ad supported is okay; I have no problem paying a reasonable price for it though. I've written Android apps before (I could write this if i had the time) and I appreciate the effort involved (especially by an individual).

Comment: Any price margin? // I cannot give a candidate (not using such), but you might wish to check my list of [Todo Apps without Synchronisation](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_todo#group_26). The numbers in the boxes after the app name are the permission counts, should make it easy to match your last requirement ;)

Comment: Personally I don't need a price for the list items. (Oh, if you meant what price would I pay, I'd say around $10 if it does everything I'm looking for) I'll check out your list, thanks.

Comment: I didn't mean a price for the items, but for the software :) Not that we recommend something you cannot (or want not) afford, when it comes to paid apps.